# Sorting datatable using ultimate date plugin not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm using datatables installed from [nugget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.datatables/1.10.15). And my table currently looks like this: [image: CurrentTable]
I would like to sort my table on "Startdatum". I added following code to the head of my view:

```
<h2>Index</h2>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>
```

And this to my datatable function which is rendered on the bottom of the view:

```
@section scripts
 {
    <script>
        //wachten tot pagina volledig ingeladen is
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.fn.dataTable.moment('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
            $("#mytable").DataTable({
                "order": [[4, "asc"]], //or asc 
                columnDefs: [
                { type: "date-euro", targets: 4 }
            ]
});
        });
    </script>
}
```

My autocomplete doesn't recognize .moment, and the table isn't sorted on time correctly as you can see in the image. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: **A** are you getting any error in your console? **B** as per the documentation [date-euro is depricated](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/date-euro).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main error is that you need other library to match with `type: "date-euro"`:

```
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/sorting/date-euro.js"></script>
```

Then, you have bad formatted dates. You are mixing dates like **1/02/2019** and **10/02/2019**. You have to use the second option, for example, in C# you have to use `myDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")` in all dates. See example below:

[image]

Finally, I'm not sure, but I think that `$.fn.dataTable.moment('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');` is not neccesary if you use `date-euro` in column def.

Comment: i used the tostring method, and replaced my second script with yours but its still not ordering correctly... i get following error in console Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at date-euro.js:24

Comment: This is because you are loading date-euro library before jquery, and you have to load it after jquery library